# ArduinoMega2560 throws avrdude: com-state error after pressing the reset button a few times

Tags: arduino-mega, hardware

I have recently switched to an ArduinoMega2560 (authentic) from the Arduino Uno and have been having a bit of trouble with uploading sketches after the reset button has been pressed a few times. This is the sketch I am using to test:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("hello world");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("testing");
  delay(1000);
}
```

When I was using the Uno, the sketch would automatically run when the sketch is uploaded. When the reset button is pressed the sketch restarts ("hello world" is printed followed by "testing" every second). I can press the reset button any number of times and the sketch restarts with no issue. This is what I believe to be the expected behavior.

With the Mega however things have been unpredictable. When the sketch is uploaded it sometimes runs but other times not (haven't figured out the pattern if there is one) and after pressing the reset button it sometimes works, sometimes not. I have noticed that after the reset button a few times (3-5 times on average) then the following com-state error occurs:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\Crustus\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM3
         Using Programmer              : wiring
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\\.\COM3"
avrdude: ser_drain(): read error: The handle is invalid.


avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

If I try upload a sketch again after this it just times out.

Any idea what the issue could be? I have changed COM ports and tried but don't think it is a  COM port issue as the Uno works but perhaps that assumption is wrong.

Does the reset button work differently on the Uno and Mega perhaps?

I am using the ArduinoIDE (2.0.0-rc9.3).I have found a few instances of variations of this issue across the forums but have not found one resolved or relating to the reset button and it working intermittently.

Comment: try it with IDE 1. IDE 2 has still many problems. if it has the problem with IDE 1, return the Mega

Comment: @Juraj Thanks, I have tried IDE 1 and it has produced the same result

Comment: Are you testing this with nothing connected to the Mega board except the computer?

Comment: @timemage yes, nothing else connected

Comment: I am unable to replicate your problem using your code on an Arduino MEGA ADK, which is essentially the same board except having integrated USB host shield. Tested under Windows 10, IDE v1.8.9 as distributed from the Windows Store (v1.8.57.0), AVR boards package v1.8.5. You are resetting with just the reset button, right? Your board is not laying on top of a conductive surface would short when downward pressure was applied? Otherwise provide any other detail you can think might allow recreating the problem.

Comment: @timemage Thanks, appreciate the effort. I am resetting with the reset button and the board was not on a conductive surface - but good thing to note for future. Ended up reinstalling the IDE again and it seemed to fix it for now. IDE 2 still produces the same error (AVR v1.8.5) but IDE 1 (also AVR v1.8.5) works so guess I'll be going back to that. I am on Windows 11 so maybe something funky going on there. Thanks again.